# How to check number of simultaneous open connections on Cisco firewall?

Tags: cisco

Looking through a log on a Cisco PIX, when it's disconnected from the network I can see this line:

`%PIX-6-302010: 7 in use, 128 most used`

Is there a command I can run that will give me this info? (without pulling the network cable out of the firewall!) It's useful to see the number of current, simultaneous connections and also the peak figure. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for just connections or VPN users?

Just connections, log in to the device in enable mode and run:

```
sh conn count
```